# List name from a variable

Tags: python, list, variables

How can I use a variable name as the name of a list?
The first print statement gives a `1`, that's correct, but the last line gives a character `m` because it is the first char of the string `my_list`.
Instead, I want the first item from `my_list`.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
word = "my_list"
print(my_list[0])  # 1
print(word[0])  # "m"
```

Comment: try `word = my_list`

Comment: In one word: don't do *variable variables.* What's the point?

Comment: While what you want is _possible_, it's rarely a good idea. If you want to access things by a name string put them in a `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

This is poor practice. Do not name variables using strings.

A better idea is to use a dictionary to store your value, utilizing a string key for your identifier.

For example:

```
my_list = [1,2,3]

d = {'word': my_list}
```

Then access via `d['word']`.

Comment: This was the plan: I had a couple of lists with names like men1, men2 , men3, etc. and wanted to get the right list, dependable on some input. So "men" + var. Now, I realise that I'd better make one nested list. Thanks all.

Comment: @DickStada, You can still implement your plan. Just use a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, clever solution. Tried it out and works great! Thanks a lot.